# How to click a button using java

Tags: java, jquery, html

I need to extract all the information from the page, but part of html code is hidden. To see more I need to click a button

```html
 <div class="respButton respBigButton prodLoadOpinions" data-page="2">Załaduj więcej</div>
```

[image: This orange smth is a button =)]

What should I use to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: **Not possible**. You cannot use Java to click a button. Java runs either on the server side or as an applet, and it doesn't have access to the HTML Elements. You need to use either JavaScript or jQuery to interact with the elements.

Comment: You can use Selenium WebDriver http://www.seleniumhq.org/. It will allow you to control your browser from java code

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible**. You cannot use Java to click a button. Java runs either on the server side or as an applet, and it doesn't have access to the HTML Elements. You need to use either JavaScript or jQuery to interact with the elements.

But if you are using jQuery, as I can see it has been tagged, you could use `.click()` function or `.trigger("click")` on the element this way:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".prodLoadOpinions").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="respButton respBigButton prodLoadOpinions" data-page="2">Załaduj więcej</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), its a framework designed for web testing. It can do everything you can through the browser, with code.

Comment: I decided to use Selenium, but the problem is next - I need to click a button several times (until it disappear) And I wrote the following code:   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.navigate().to(url);
  WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.className("respBigButton"));
  while (button != null){
   Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
   actions.moveToElement(button).click().perform();
   button = driver.findElement(By.className("respBigButton"));
  }

Comment: And I have next Exception - Element is no longer attached to the DOM     Did u have smth similiar to this?

Comment: I will have to write some code to help you out, but at first glance your code looks OK. Just a small thing, you don't need that Action thing, every WebElement has click() method, so once you obtain the button by class name, just call button.click()

Comment: You want to say, that it`will be better to use next code: while (button.isDisplayed() { button.click();  button = new driver.findElement(By.className("respBigButton"));} ??